# Sections of Questions As Subclass in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have a class of questions with different sections - certain sections are shown to the user depending on other answers. Section 1 is always answered. Section 2 & 3 are only answered in some cases.

How should I best "group" these questions so that I can easily check the **total number of true** answers in a given group (contains `true`/`false`) and check that the sections has **every question answered**?

---

The data in the questions is coming back from a web UI in a Spring project. I think the possible values are `true`, `false` or `null`.

```
@Entity
public class LicenseApplication {
    // Section 1
    private boolean question1;
    private boolean question2;

    //Section 2
    private boolean question3;
    private boolean question4;
}
```

Comment: define a class `Section` and put your all requirement into it

Comment: Like nested classes?

Comment: more like 2 separate classes that use each other...

Comment: Please don't have a separate variable for every question.  You may want to learn about arrays at this point.

Comment: Also is `Questions()` a class or a method? Classes in Java don't have parenthesizes after them...

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to the following

```
class Section
{
    public List<Question> questions;
    //...
}

class Question
{
    public boolean isCorrect;
    //...
}

public boolean entireSectionCorrect(Section section)
{
    for (int i=0; i<section.questions.size(); i++) {
        if(!section.questions[i].isCorrect)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Two things: 1) You are returning `void` instead of `bool` in the method signature. 2) You should `return-early` instead of maintaining a `result` var...  To do that, get rid of all `result`references, and do `/*inside for-loop*/ if(!section.questions[i].isCorrect) return false; /*after for-loop*/ return true;`

Comment: @AlanCPSC sorry I edited the question after your answer. Would you hard code the questions for each section into the questions array?

Comment: @DougGreaney Basically the only thing his answer doesn't (directly) address if `so that I can easily check the total number of true answers in a given group` --- That can easily be accomplished with a `counting loop` very similar to the current implementation of the `entireSectionCorrect` method: `/*method signature = int*/ int count = 0; for(Question question : questions) if(question.isCorrect) count++; return count;`

Comment: @DougGreaney Doug, there is no "correct" way to do any of this. Its programming. There is a 10 million ways to do anything. Just pick one that suits your current needs and stick with it.

Comment: @DougGreaney AFAICS, nothing wrong... Your classes are too simple to actually require separation... I don't know if you have code you haven't shown us, but as far as what you've shown goes, implementing the array/list and the checks inside of the `Question` class, and getting rid of `Section` entirely seems to be a good option, if not the best option. =)

Comment: Isn't questions a list of instances of the class rather than a list of selected attributes from the class? ie Question1 and Question2?

Comment: @DougGreaney Isn't `Question` just a `bool` field? Because that's what you've shown us, and in that sense, as far as we know, there is no practical difference between (`Question`)`questions[i].isCorrect` and (`bool`)`questions[i]`. --- If you want to make the array/list as the `bool` directly, go right ahead! 

Comment: @AlanCPSC The maintenance of a redundant `result` variable is bothering me too much ... I'm just gonna go ahead and edit it myself before I go crazy... 

Answer (score 0):

@AlanCPSC has good suggestion, as correcting few things

```
class Section
{
    private List<Question> questions;
    public int getCount()
    {     
         int count=0;
        for(Question quest : questions)
        {
             boolean answer    = quest.getAnswer().get(quest.getQuestion());
             boolean answered  = quest.getAnswered().get(quest.getQuestion());
            if(answer == answered)
            {
              count++;
            }
        }
         return count;
    }
    ...
}

class Question
{
    private String question;
    private Map<String, Boolean> answer; // correct answer
    private Map<String, Boolean> answered; // answered by candidate
    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't thing the OP is ready for the usage of `private` or for `Map` just yet... He is already struggling to grasp `array` and `public` after all...  --- It's cool to push the OP a little, but this is too much and is just going to be confusing for him/her at this time, IMHO.

Comment: Not MCQ - True/False (Boolean). And The Question class is annotated with @Entity (sorry added after your answer) for Hibernate persistence.

Comment: @DougGreaney is it fine, if I use some data structure like `Map` and `List` ?

Comment: @Ravi yes but its not MCQ. Just Yes/No. That's why private Boolean question1 etc

Comment: @DougGreaney You check my post. I'm still updating. Please note, I'm not good in Hibernate stuff, so, you need to correct few of things accordingly

Comment: @Ravi thanks. There is no right wrong answer. Just a sum of Questions answered True.

Comment: @DougGreaney I have completed my post, you can make use of it and correct accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I got a little disappointed by the confusion being made by the OP and by the overkill of other answers, so here is my take...

DISCLAIMER: I have been away from java for a while now, and I've coded this by memory... Forgive any mistakes (but do point them out so I fix them).

---

```
public class Section {
    public boolean[] questions[];

    public Section(int questionAmount){
        questions = new boolean[questionAmount];
    }

    public boolean isEveryQuestionAnswered() {
        for(boolean question : questions) {
            if(!question) //If any question is not answered.
                return false;
        }

        //If reached this point, all questions were answered, so...
        return true;
    }

    public int totalNumberOfTrues() {
        int count = 0;
        for(boolean question : questions) {
            if(question) //If any question is answered.
                count++;
        }

        //If reached this point, all 'true' questions were accounted for, so...
        return count;
    }
}

public class LicenseApplication {
    private Section[] sections = new Section[3];

    // Section 1
    sections[0] = new Section(2);
    sections[0].questions[0] = false;
    sections[0].questions[1] = true;
    //...
    System.out.println("Section 1 complete: "+sections[0].isEveryQuestionAnswered()) //Prints "Section 1 complete: false"
    System.out.println("Section 1 total answered: "+sections[0].totalNumberOfTrues()) //Prints "Section 1 total answered: 1"

    //Section 2
    sections[1] = new Section(3);
    sections[1].questions[0] = true;
    sections[1].questions[1] = true;
    sections[1].questions[2] = true;
    //...
    System.out.println("Section 2 complete: "+sections[1].isEveryQuestionAnswered()) //Prints "Section 2 complete: true"
    System.out.println("Section 2 total answered: "+sections[1].totalNumberOfTrues()) //Prints "Section 2 total answered: 3"

    //INSERT [Section 3] here at will...
}
```